# Alphabetical order with special characters perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have this set of code:

```
 use strict; 
 use warnings; 
 my %hash = ( 5328 => 'Adorable', 
              26191 => '"Giraffe"', 
              57491 => 'Is Very', 
               4915 => 'Cute',);
 foreach (sort { ($hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b}) || ($a cmp $b) } keys %hash) 
 { print "$hash{$_}\n"; }
```

this will result as:

```
"Giraffe"

Adorable

Cute

Is Very
```

I need it to be ordered alphabetically, and disregard the special character before the AlphaNumeric character like in this sample:

```
Adorable

Cute

"Giraffe"

Is Very
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: build a hash with unquoted strings as keys and sort the keys. You can also trim each value in the comparison.

Comment: If the keys are numeric, you probably want to use `<=>` rather than `cmp` for the second-level sort.

Comment: Your data set is wrong. You need to remove the quotes before they get anywhere near your hash. Are you dealing with CSV data perhaps?

Comment: Please clarify: is every alternate line in your data really blank?

Comment: What is the source of the data that has built your hash `%hash` (and *please* don't call things `@array` or `%hash` or `$scalar`). It should be rewritten.

Comment: this is just a sample data, the end result doesn't necessary has to have spaces in between, i just showed it like that to make it more clear to see

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do that *(note that I changed the second `cmp` to the shuttle operator `<=>` for numeric values)*:

```
foreach (sort { ($hash{$a}=~s/^\W+//r cmp $hash{$b}=~s/^\W+//r) || ($a <=> $b) } keys %hash) {
    print "$hash{$_}\n";
}
```

But if you have a lot of data, it's better to transform your data *(once and for all)*:
For example using a schwartzian transform:

```
my @result = map { $_->[2] }
             sort { ($a->[0] cmp $b->[0]) || ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) }
             map { [ $hash{$_}=~s/^"|"$//gr, $_, $hash{$_}] } keys %hash; 

print join "\n", @result;
```

Comment: You might want to mention that you need Perl >= 5.14 to use `/r`.

Answer (score 5):

Create a function which truncates special characters (`truncate_special_chars` in my case). Then, use it under your `sort` routine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    5328 => 'Adorable',
    26191 => '"Giraffe"',
    57491 => 'Is Very',
    4915 => 'Cute',
    );


print join "\n", 
    map { $hash{$_ -> [0]} }
    sort { $a -> [1] cmp $b -> [1] || $a -> [0] <=> $b -> [0] }
    map { [ $_, truncate_special_chars($hash{$_}) ] }
    keys %hash;

sub truncate_special_chars {
    my $str = shift;
    $str =~ s/^\W//;
    # may be use lc if you want case insensitive sort
    return $str;
}
```

Otherwise you can use `/r` if you are using `Perl >= 5.14`.

Comment: You missed the case where `$hash{$a} == $hash{$b}`, it must be ordered by key.

Comment: @Toto Edited. I guess, it would be trivial, If I carry key instead of value :).

Comment: I think you should do numeric comparison for the hash keys: `sort { $a -> [1] cmp $b -> [1] || $a -> [0] <=> $b -> [0] }`.

Comment: @jreisinger Done.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom sort function that strips out the characters you want to ignore.

```
foreach (sort {
            my ($aa,$bb) = ($hash{$a},$hash{$b});
            s/["]//g for $aa,$bb; # ignore " char. Add whatever else you want
            $aa cmp $bb           # or lc($aa) cmp lc($bb) case-insensitive search
                || $a cmp $b
       } keys %hash) { ... }
```

Comment: You could include a Schwartzian transform to make it faster. Stripping out stuff all the time is expensive.

Comment: Yes, a Schwartzian transform is worthwhile when the input is large and the transformations to the input before comparing are expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
my %hash = ( 5328 => 'Adorable', 
      26191 => '"Giraffe"', 
      57491 => 'Is Very', 
       4915 => 'Cute',);

foreach (sort{my ($one)=$hash{$a}=~m/([\w\s]+)/; my ($two)=$hash{$b}=~m/([\w\s]+)/; $one cmp $two} keys %hash) 
{ 
    print "$hash{$_}\n"; 
}
```

Group the elements and store into `$one` and `$two` then compare it.

But it is very easy with [@Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557647/alphabetical-order-with-special-characters-perl/41562167#41557827) answer. He used [non-destructive modifier(r).](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) but it will support above the 5.14 version